# GWT в Eclipse: проблема установки и настройки

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, java, eclipse

Установил Eclipse Classic 3.7 с [офф. сайта](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) и установил к нему плагин GWT в соответствии с [инструкцией на google](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-3.7.html). Дополнительно еще установил [GWT Designer](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner.html).
Но, при следовании инстукциям [быстрого старта](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/quick_start.html) по их скриншотами видми, что наш Ecplipse не такой как у них. При Alt+Shift+N или Ctrl+N подсписок GWT урезанный, в отличии от скрина в [инстукции](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/features/editing_existing_window.html).

В чем проблема, не могу разобраться, версия Eclipse, GWT неправильно установил...?
Как можно добавить в Eclipse SmartGWT?
Может стоит перейти на другой IDE?
Если можно, ответы поподробнее и инструкцию от установки среды до создания проекта, добавление компонентов на форму и обработка событий при помощи GWT Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для SmartGWT я использовал

http://uptick.com.au/blog?page=5

шел от "конца" их списка примеров к началу. Там же есть ссылка для установки GWT. (но вообще этих ссылок в сети много, какими я пользовался вначале, не помню)

Eclipse у меня похоже выглядит тоже не совсем, как в примерах (старая версия была более похожа). Я не стал заморачиваться, компилит, работает, и ладно.

Для SmartGWT в Eclipse главное не забыть:

1). добавить в properties проекта в JavaBuidPath AddExternalJars файлы smartgwt.jar и smartgwt-skins.jar

2). в .../src/.../my-proj-name.gwt.xml после  (идиотский форматер, символ меньше в строке нельзя)

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
добавить
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt"/>
```

Еще одно, Google App Engine при создании проекта я отключаю.

Comment: Действительно, похоже в инструкциях google, версия Eclipse отличается от 3.7, просто потому, что у них использована старая версия.  
Google App Engine отключаете почему?

Comment: Нарвался на проблемы с открытием файлов и отправкой почты на сервере. Думаю, другие тоже есть. Да и не нужен он для наших (на работе)  задач, как мне сказали.

Comment: В <a href="http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/release_notes.html#2_5">Release Notes for Smart GWT 2.5</a> написано "Added GWT 2.3 support. Dropped support for GWT 1.5.x", это значит GWT 2.4 еще не поддерживается?

Comment: Не знаю. У меня в Proprties -> Java Build Path стоит GWT SDK [GWT - 2.3.0]

Comment: Несмотря на Release Notes, проблем с Smart GWT 2.5 и GWT 2.4 не возникает, GWT Designer тоже функционирует нормально.